# Remote Build Azure Function w/Timer in Python

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm working with Timer Azure Function in python, it's a linux based function, and looking to write to blob.

```
# __init__.py

import datetime
import logging
import random 

import azure.functions as func

import os, sys

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, outputBlob: func.Out[str]):
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer2 trigger function ran at %s %d' % (utc_timestamp, random.randint(1, 21)))

output = "Hello World!"
outputblob.set(output)
```

here is the function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "lakesensecontainer/clear.txt",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=conectionstring"
    }
  ]
}
```

Get this error: Extensions command requires dotnet on your path. Please make sure to install dotnet (.NET Core SDK) for your system from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download.  I've installed on my local, but that seems is irrelevant as it's trying to write to remote.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

We’re trying to make this default in all tools / templates but it’s saying it doesn’t have the “extension” for the timer trigger and trying to use dotnet to install it.  The easiest fix (and what defaults should be moving forward) is to copy the content from this doc into your host.json letting the azure function use a “bundle” that has a bunch of extensible functionality like timers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
}
```

}